# What can I do about high pressure water noise?

Tags: plumbing

I have for many years had loud noise that sounds like high pressure water rushing through the pipes. This happens whenever water is turned on in our villa and the duplex next door. The pressure outside our home is 92psi and inside 88psi. Plumbers have tried to fix this problem many times but now the pressure is higher and the noise louder. This has become very distressing and we need help. We live in a retirement village and the manager has refused to try and fix the problem any more. Please help us.

Comment: Well, what are allowed to do? If it's water hammer, you could install air traps all over the place Do you have access to the shutoff valve? Usually you can close it more to reduce pressure (looks like what your hose connects to usually and it works the same). And it is on a lot of water appliances I guess? Turn those down too. Do you have any pipes not firmly fixed to the walls/floors/ceilings?

Answer (score 1):

Your water pressure is very high - nearly double the average pressure.

The solution is very simple - install a pressure-reducing valve in the water main just after the meter and main shutoff valve. The valves are in the $100-$200 range from any commercial plumbing supplier (Home Depot probably doesn't have them).

However, this involves modifying the house utilities and is therefore definitely in the owner's domain. Both you and the neighbor will likely have to approach him together, unless you can do the job yourself without anyone noticing.

Comment: Home Depot; and likely other big box stores, sell [pressure reducing valves](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Watts-3-4-in-Brass-FPT-x-FPT-Pressure-Reducing-Valve-3-4-LF25AUB-Z3/202922385).

Answer (score -1):

Shrieking, shaking & rattling pipes & walls, is a very simple fix. It's actually a harmonic imbalance & quite common, though most plumbers don't know about it & try to fool around with the faucets.

Just turn your faucet on fully & then go beneath & slowly turn down the shut-off valve until everything settles down. Do this with the cold water & the hot water separately. You're just capping off the flow & shouldn't notice any flow difference. Some faucets just have a design that's not agreeable & can be quieted down beautifully.